# Que hago para hacer un efecto typing pero a la inversa?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Buenaas, necesito ayudaa. Quiero hacer un efecto typing pero al revés. me explico, tengo ya un efecto typing que va desde width 0 hasta el width del string. El tema es que quiero que al llegar al final del recorrido, despues de aprox 5 o 3 segundos, el efecto se haga a la inversa haciendo desaparecer las letras para luego hacer aparecer otra frase de la misma manera, y que el typing al revés la haga desaparecer y así en bucle.
adjunto mi codigo:

```
    .me span {
    display: block;
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-right: 4px solid;
    width: 17ch;
    animation: typing 2s steps(12), blink .5s infinite step-end alternate;
    overflow: hidden;

    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

@keyframes typing {
    from {width: 0}
}

@keyframes blink {
    50% {
        border-color: transparent;
    }
}
```

gracias por su tiempo y respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
         .me span {
    display: block;
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-right: 4px solid;
    width: 17ch;
    animation: typing 2s steps(12) alternate infinite, blink .5s infinite step-end alternate;
    overflow: hidden;

    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

@keyframes typing {
    from {width: 0}
}

@keyframes blink {
    50% {
        border-color: transparent;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="me"><span>HOLA MUNDO!</span></div>
```